# Using grep with word boundary for a numeric range

Tags: grep

Hi I'm trying to use grep for a specific range of values which are tail ended by a word.

eg "000RJ" - "015RJ"  from a larger range.

What would be the most effective way to do this please?

Comment: Can you give a sample input and expected output out of that?

Comment: I was planning on taking everything from one file and outputting to another file like this  grep "000KT" - "015KT" fileA.txt > FileB.txt

Comment: The input file has millions of rows in the format XXX NNNNNX NN011KT N/NXX XXXX XX XXX XXXNNN XXXNNN XNN/XNN XXNNN XXX XXX

Comment: I'm just interested in extracting all rows with the values between 000KT - 015KT into a new file.  The new format is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` with numerical range expansions like,

```
grep -w '0[0-1][0-5]KT' fileA.txt
```

to expand numbers from range `000-015`.

Comment: Yes that is what I wanted.  Thank you very much

Comment: @AlwinSolanky: Happy to help!